# Changing observablearray value from viewmodel function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I have a function in my view model that should change the enabled value in my array from false to true.

```
  editclick: function (user) {
     user.enabled = true;
     return true;
  }
```

If I put an alert to show the change

```
user.enabled = true;
alert(ko.toJSON(user));
```

It shows it did change but the bind value does not change.

If I put an alert in front of the change

```
alert(ko.toJSON(user));
user.enabled = true;
```

the second time I click the button the alert does show the value changed.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JanGous/npBmq/) as well as the code I use.

**[JS]**

```
var myViewModel = {
  myarray: ko.observableArray([{
     myname: 'Bob',
     mysurname: 'Smith',
     enabled: false
  }, {
     myname: 'John',
     mysurname: 'Smith',
     enabled: false
  }]),
  editclick: function (user) {
     user.enabled = true;
     alert(ko.toJSON(user));
     return true;
  }
};
```

**[CODE]**

```
<Table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Button</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: myarray">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Change" data-bind="click: $root.editclick" />
        </td>
        <td><span data-bind="text: enabled" />
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</Table>
```

I seems that the change does not update the viewmodel.
Is there away to make this work.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ko.observableArray` only tracks item addition or removal.

So in order to KO track the changes inside of the items and automatically updates the UI you need to make the properties `ko.observable`:

```
myarray: ko.observableArray([{
         myname: 'Bob',
         mysurname: 'Smith',
         enabled: ko.observable(false)
     }, {
         myname: 'John',
         mysurname: 'Smith',
         enabled: ko.observable(false)
     }])
```

and in your `editclick` you need to set the `enabled` with: `user.enabled(true);` (because the `ko.observable` returns a function)

```
editclick: function (user) {
         user.enabled(true);
         alert(ko.toJSON(user));
         return true;
     }
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rRMu3/)